# O que fazer quando o Avast detecta uma ameça num aplicativo inofensivo?

Tags: visual-studio

Fiz um stresser de rede, nenhum vírus, e o bendito Avast! Alerta e destrói meu projeto:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Tentou adicionar esse executavel na lista de exceções do avast?

Comment: Tem um "Informe que o arquivo é um falso positivo" alí no popup.

Comment: Já adicionei, mas o Avast é bugado, não adianta.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Alguns programas anti-vírus consideram que um aplicativo é uma potencial ameaça quando o desenvolvedor não assina o aplicativo com uma chave digital.

Tente adicionar uma chave ao seu projeto e verifique se o problema persiste.

Por exemplo, você pode ver como se assina digitalmente um projeto pelo Visual Studio nessa página:

> ### [VB 2005 - Assinando Assemblies com nomes fortes](http://www.macoratti.net/vbn5_asa.htm)
>
> Quando você cria um projeto .NET no Visual Studio 2005 ele é compilado na forma de um assembly. Por padrão este assembly esta aberto e não possui nenhuma segurança que assegure aos usuários da aplicação que eles estão usando a versão correta do arquivo binário.
>
> Você contorna este problema assinando o seu assembly através da atribuição de  um 'nome forte' para a aplicação compilada ou componente a qual pode desta forma ser identificada de forma única por outras aplicações e administradores de sistemas que podem então aplicar uma política de segurança para a aplicação. Assim você pode garantir que um nome seja globalmente exclusivo assinando um assembly com um nome forte.
>
> Antes de mostrar diretamente como você pode assinar os seus assemblies, tornando-os assim mais seguros e confiáveis, vamos abordar alguns conceitos básicos como: Global Assembly Cache e assemblies fortemente nomeados.

Comment: Ele já foi assinado pelo **ClickOnce**, mas não resolveu, e a chave que estou usando é um certificado original da Windows Store!

Comment: Obrigado pela edição, @brasofilo. Com o sumário e link em hyperlink realmente fica mais claro ter um preview do que está na página linkada.